# write to new row every xth element java csv write

Tags: java, csv

Using an answer I found here on SO I have found a way to write out my resultset to a csv file.  However it currently just writes every element of the array to a new column.  How would I alter the following code to change format to create new row, on every xth element like below?

```
int value = 2
Current format:  a, b, c, d, e, f

Desired format: a, b,
                c, d,
                e, f
```

I know I can utilize the modulo of the int value, but am unsure how to write to a specific column or row.

```
private static final String DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = " ";

 public static void writeLine(Writer w, List<String> values, String separators, String customQuote) throws IOException {

    boolean first = true;

    //default customQuote is empty

    if (separators == " ") {
        separators = DEFAULT_SEPARATOR;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String value : values) {
        if (!first) {
            sb.append(separators);
        }
        if (customQuote == " ") {
            sb.append(followCVSformat(value));
        } else {
            sb.append(customQuote).append(followCVSformat(value)).append(customQuote);
        }

        first = false;
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    w.append(sb.toString());


}


private static String followCVSformat(String value) {

        String result = value;
        if (result.contains("\"")) {
            result = result.replace("\"", "\"\"");
        }
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Which answer do you refer to? Please show your efforts, i.e. provide a [mcve] by [edit]ing your question

Comment: Please include your current code.

Comment: My apologies, it got cut out.  I have added the method I am using to write to the CSV.

Comment: I recommend using Apache Commons CSV library to write CSV, it does what you need and so much more.

Comment: What is DEFAULT_SEPARATOR? What does the followCVSformat() method do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void writeLine(
        Writer w, List<String> values, String separators, String customQuote, int elementsPerRow)
        throws IOException {
    ...
    int counter = 0;
    for (String value : values) {
        if (!first) {
            sb.append(separators);
        }
        if (counter != 0 && counter % elementsPerRow == 0)
            sb.append("\n");
        if (customQuote == " ") {
            sb.append(followCVSformat(value));
        } else {
            sb.append(customQuote).append(followCVSformat(value)).append(customQuote);
        }
        first = false;
        counter++;
    }
    ...
```